# mysql_query Select limited at 525 results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select and is limited at 525 results otherwise the while will stuck.

```
    $query_other = "SELECT * FROM prod where active=1 and aprobat=1";
    $other = mysql_query($query_other, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($other)){
        $other_prod[]=$row;
    }
```

In cpanel it shows more than 525 and when i did var_dump on $other its says resource(525) of type (mysql result). Its on Apache Server if that helps.

If i put LIMIT 525 it works and show all page otherwise is just blank page. Anything after the while doesn't work.

P.S : I know mysql_ is deprecated i hate it but is required at the task and i have no power over it.

Comment: Check the error log. Most likely you're just running out of memory. `resource(525)` is just a fatal coincidence :-D Number in parentheses has no connection with the actual data.

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut: 24M of RAM should be enough for everyone, indeed.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of the RAM problem.. but i will see if this is the case.

Comment: Maybe it's not the mysql problem. Have you look at the memory limit of php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing memory won't help. It's just a temporary fix. Plus you need to think of multiple clients doing the same query at the same time. How's the system going to keep up with the memory consumption.

***BUT** be selective about the [fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/c-api-data-structures.html) you need to pull back.*

**Don't**:

```
SELECT *
```

**Do**:

```
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, ...
```

This will decrease memory consumption and let you deal with things. I imagine you don't need all the rows. And you especially want to avoid `TEXT`/`BLOB` ones as they are usually large. Select them only when you need to display/use them.

**You can also use**:

```
LIMIT 0, 100
```

to paginate through the results. Might help you a bit but I'd select the right fields to fix this permanently.

**Also set**:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);
```

and see if PHP tells you more about what goes wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry In the `MySQL C library`, they're called [fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/c-api-data-structures.html). ;)

Comment: Maybe. They definitely aren't called rows.

Comment: did with the fields and the limit will hurt the other code that is in there that i "shouldn't touch"(team stuff). Still it gives the error and i have only 4 fields ...

Comment: @user2984950 Get [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and test your query in there. See how many bytes it returns, speed and better error reporting.

Comment: I will accept your answer and paginate somehow. Thank you very much didn't think the RAM is so little for query's.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is indeed memory, you can increase it dynamically with this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M"); //i.e. change the memory_limit to 512M, you should specify more than current limit.
```

Comment: ok i need access for that right? i mean the php ini? because in the php file doesn't work at all.

Comment: no you don't. you just need to put this at the start of your php file. this php.ini value can be changed dynamically from php.

Comment: ok it doesn't work for some reason and i can't figure it out.